# How to Use ResNet or VGGNet for image Classification

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning, pre-trained-model

I am new to Deep Learning and was trying to implement ResNet and VGGNet architecture on my own dataset of binary classification between roads and grass.

When i use the pretrained ResNet or VGG model they dont classify the images as road and grass

I want to learn how to manually set the output classes
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem falls into one of the transfer learning approaches, which is *using pre-trained model (e.g., `ResNet` and `VGGNet`) as a feature extractor*.

This is because your dataset and the dataset used to train the pre-trained models are different. They were learned from the ImageNet dataset aimed to classify images into 1000 object categories. This means that you can't apply every part of the pre-trained model.

The CNN pre-trained model can be split into 2 main parts:

1. feature extractor: groups of ConV and Pooling layer
2. classifier: fully connected NN

In your case, you can use only their feature extractor part by freezing or fine-tuning them, and **you require to add your own classifier** to fit with your classification task.

Comment: can you please share a resource depicting how to do the same , thanks

Comment: I think this (https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/cnn-transfer-learning-with-vgg-16-and-resnet-50-feature-extraction-for-image-retrieval-with-keras-53320c580853) can help you. See the "Transfer Learning with VGG-16 and ResNet-50" part on this link.